# gzip, send to server, ungzip

Tags: scripting, tar, gzip

I am working on a script to backup and gzip a set of MySQL tables, scp/ssh them to a different server and then unpack them
current script is:

```
#!/bin/bash

DATE=`date +"%d_%b_%Y_%H%M"`
BACKUP_DIR=/mnt/data/backups/saturday/

echo Creating new directory /mnt/data/backups/saturday/fathom_$DATE
sudo mkdir /mnt/data/backups/saturday/fathom_$DATE
sudo chmod 777 /mnt/data/backups/saturday/fathom_$DATE

mysqldump pacific_fathom user_types > /mnt/data/backups/saturday/fathom_$DATE/user_types.sql
echo Dumping users ...
mysqldump pacific_fathom users > /mnt/data/backups/saturday/fathom_$DATE/users.sql
echo Dumping users_roles ...
mysqldump pacific_fathom users_roles > /mnt/data/backups/saturday/fathom_$DATE/users_roles.sql

tar -zvcpf $BACKUP_DIR/PlatformDB-$DATE.tar.gz /mnt/data/backups/saturday/fathom_* | ssh root@xx.xx.xx.xx 'tar -xzf - -C /mnt/data/backups/saturday'

echo Finished!
```

the backup works and it will zip the files but it tells me it errors with

```
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

The output file it creates is `PlatformDB-22_Jul_2021_1553.tar.gz`

It never moves to the ssh part (checked last in the remote server and there are no logins there) so I am a bit confused as to why I am get this error. The tar.gz file it creates can be unpacked using the `tar -xzf - -C /mnt/data/backups/saturday` part of the script. I do have to replace the `-` with the file name. I do not think that would make a difference in the script though. Also that would not work in an automated environment. Any help would be GREATLY appreaciated!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command `tar -zvcpf ...$DATE.tar.gz /mnt/data/backups/saturday/fathom_*` writes the gzipped backup to `$DATE.tar.gz` and outputs the list of files that are backed up.

This file list is then piped into `ssh root@xx.xx.xx.xx 'tar -xzf - ...`. Obviously, the file list is not in gzipped format, which causes the error.

**Solution**: Send the content of `$DATE.tar.gz` to the ssh command. For example first create the local backup file, then `cat $DATE.tar.gz | ssh ...`. Or, if you don't need the local backup file, create the backup on standard output:

```
tar -zvcpf - /mnt/data/backups/saturday/fathom_* | ssh ...
```

You can also try the `tee` command and write the backup to both standard output and a local file:

```
tar -zvcpf - /mnt/data/backups/saturday/fathom_* | tee $DATE.tar.gz | ssh ...
```

As a side remark not really relevant to this question, I just noticed that tar writes the file list to stdout when the archive is written to a file, and to stderr when the archive is written to stdout. Smart!